# C functions to update both user and kernel space timezone?

Tags: c, linux, time, linux-kernel, timezone

I tried both `tzset()` and `settimeofday()`. But it seems `tzset()` only changes the user space timezone, without affecting the kernel space; while `settimeofday()` only updates the kernel timezone.

Code to test `tzset()`:

```
oldtz = getenv("TZ");
putenv((char*)"TZ=UTC0");
tzset();
```

Code to test `settimeofday()`:

```
struct timeval tv;
struct timezone tz;
gettimeofday(&tv, &tz);
tz.tz_minuteswest -= 3*60; 
settimeofday(&tv, &tz);
```

Any idea of how to change both the user-space and kernel-space timezone at once?

Comment: The kernel does have or need a timezone.  It works in UTC only.  All timezone stuff is user-space.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I also found similar explanations. Although documents say the `tz` parameter of `settimeofday()` is obsolete, my above code still can change the kernel timezone - the kernel under test is 3.4.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the kernel timezone'?  Where is the kernel timezone stored?  Can you show the source code?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The kernel timezone is defined in linux/kernel/time.c: `struct timezone sys_tz; EXPORT_SYMBOL(sys_tz);`. I used kernel function `time_to_tm(get_seconds(), -sys_tz.tz_minuteswest * 60, &tm);` to convert UTC time to local time. After calling `settimeofday()` from user space to change the timezone, the kernel space local time `tm` changed as expected. User space `settimeofday()` finally calls kernel API `SYSCALL_DEFINE2(settimeofday, struct timeval __user *, tv, struct timezone __user *, tz)`.

Comment: OK; I withdraw my comments.